# Fury of dracula: skipping your turn as the hunters

Tags: fury-of-dracula

Apparently in the game (Fury of dracula, third edition) you, as a hunter, can skip your turn and do nothing. Personally I think this defeats the purpose of supplying at night. I think a lot of people will skip their night turn in later turns because they have a big disadvantage supplying as that could be there only action left.

From the rules reference book:

> During the hunter phase, each hunter performs one action during the
>   day and one action during the night.
>
> - During each day and each night, hunters perform actions in activation    order.
> - Hunters can only perform move actions during the day.
> - If a hunter is in a sea zone during the day, he must move by    sea—he cannot    pass.
> - If a hunter is in a sea zone during the night, he must pass—he       cannot perform an action.
> - If a hunter is delayed, he must stand his    figure upright instead    of performing an action.
> - ***A hunter can forfeit his action by passing.***
>
> Related Topics: Movement, Reserve a Ticket, Search, Supply, Trade

You can find the pdf [here](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/5c/e4/5ce45c7b-20f0-4737-b913-cb1e77fdb926/gw09_rules_reference.pdf).

Isn't this a big disadvantage for dracula?

This way he will never/almost never get any dracula event cards late in the game and will be on his own with the cards he has.

Is there a way to forego this rule or would that make it to difficult for the hunters?

Comment: Which version of the game and where in the rule book do you find this?

Comment: @NathanHase I'll edit the question and add that in

Comment: It would still be good to specify which version you're playing. There are three versions of this game. The original from 1987, 2nd ed from 2006 and 3rd ed from 2015.

Comment: @NathanHase It's in the description

Answer (score 2):

While passing a Hunter turn has the potential to deny Dracula a card, it will surely make the Hunter turn non-productive. I would consider this to be a wash, generally speaking.

Only one situation forces the player to pass:

> If a hunter is in a sea zone during the night, he must pass.

The benefits/detriments of passing will be situation specific. Perhaps during the late game as the Hunters close in on Dracula it would be beneficial for one Hunter to pass in order to get to the next Hunter. There are many potential scenarios to consider.

That said, passing is generally unlikely. It is in the rules as a realistic option that may occasionally be useful as well as legitimizing the forced pass by making passing an action that can be taken deliberately.